# Using POST method to get an ID will fail (returning null)

Tags: php, html, post

I am using this script to make the stuff on the landing page work. This is how it looks like:

```
   <form action="newpost.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['recoverPost']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" class="recoverButton" name="recoverPost" value=" <? echo $post_id; ?>" />
        </form>
```

However, everything else works (including the landing page when i insert the id manually), but I'd want to get the ID automatically. This is my attempt on this, but the code will not get the ID for some reason that I am not able to find out.
This is how the PHP itself looks like:

`$db` is connection with the database.

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, category_id, posted FROM deletedPosts ORDER BY post_id DESC");
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $category, $posted_date);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're sending the `id` as part of the URL, which makes it a GET argument, even though the form method is POST

Comment: When i use get it does this with the url though: `/newpost.php?recoverPost=+117`

Why does it add the **+** and how do i get rid of it ?

Comment: @estXcrew You have an extra space: `value=" <?`. Remove it: `value="<?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know interpreted exactly, but I think here you went wrong,
your first line should be,

```
 <form action="newpost.php?id=<?php echo $some_variable; ?>" method="post">
```

use $_POST to receive values from other forms !